# Best practices Use == or isSameDay apex date

Tags: apex, date, bestpractice

Currently in production I check if two dates are identical in apex by doing date1 == date2

I see in the documentation that there is also isSameDay

Would you know if using == between two dates is a good practice or if it is better to use isSameDay?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main difference is that `==` (equality operator) is null safe, while `Date.isSameDay()` is not, so I would prefer the first over the latter.
I.E.

```java
Date d1 = System.today();
Date d2; // default null
System.debug(d1 == d2); // false
System.debug(d1.isSameDay(d2)); // NullPointerException: Argument cannot be null
```

Please also note that unlike Java, `==` in Apex compares object value equality not reference equality, except for user-defined types.

Comment: Mostly true, but note that you can override `Boolean equals(Object o)` on a user-defined type to force `==` to behave however you want.